# Why do eclipse error dissappear when I copy paste code to new file

Tags: eclipse, buildpath

I've recently had to move my code from one pc to another (oddly enough a windows terminal to a linux desktop).

fortunately (at least I thought) I had regularly exported the code using the export function in eclipse, and saved the copy onto a USB key.

So I simply 'imported' the code I had on the key into a new workspace on my new desktop. Things seemed happy and jolly. Obviously I needed to fix a few issues with paths and locations of libraries I had used, and make minor updates to some ant files. Nothing to major.

After having done all this I expected the various build path errors that I was getting would be resolved. Unfortunately not.

After much messing around with the various build paths of the files that where causing me grief I decided I would try to simple copy and paste the code in the files into a new class.

So I renamed the original class (appending _old to the name using eclipses refactor process). I created a new java class file, then copy / pasted the code frome the _old file to the new one, obviously I altered the name of the class and the constructor on the way.

The new files throw out no build path error, or anything else that concerns me (I still have some unused imports, but I will tidy these up when my development has finished for these libraries)

My question is, is this a problem with Eclipse (I'm still using indigo as I found juno very slow?), and if so, how can I troubleshoot to create a sensible bug report?

Or is it something else that I did wrong in my export / import ?

Thanks in advance for any comments.

David.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what went wrong because you obviously executed a lot of manual steps in between "then" and "now". A few hints though:

- You can export/import all workspace preferences if you like (File -> Export -> General/Preferences).
- You know about Project -> Build Automatically or Project -> Clean?
- You can eliminate unused imports automatically through project or workspace preferences -> Java Editor -> Save Actions

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I did a number of manual steps it wasn't anything major other than the adjustment for the 'new location' as linux has a different set up from windows, so importing all workspace preferences wouldn't have worked. Is the project -> Clean the same as refresh ? I'm not sure I remember seeing 'project' in the menus. As I say about the imports I'll clean them up once I'm ready for release, as I may find I need to go back to 'tweak' out bugs (ie comment out code on a temp basis, then test all my dependent stuff before deciding I don't need the import anymore).